# Safari is very slow

Tags: safari

I have been noticing that Safari has gotten very slow lately. Has anyone else had this issue recently?

It must have been after some update, could have been some time ago so I won't know which, maybe Sierra, Safari has become very slow when loading pages. It is not a connection issue as I have tried it at different places, also it can't be a issue with the settings, as I ran into the problem again even with a brand new MacBook Pro.

I could use chrome but I don't want to :)

Answer (score 1):

Tested your [network connection speed](http://www.testmyspeed.com)?

I recently had a similar performance hit with Safari. Not sure [what caused it](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7353513?start=0&tstart=0), but I did this and it hasn't come back:

1. Open the Activity Monitor
   (it's an an application available in the `/Applications/Utilities/` folder
   <kbd>Cmd⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> from the Finder.)
2. See if there is a process called "Safari Networking" hogging the CPU%.
3. Kill it.

[image]

Possibly [related to Gmail](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/178001/216401)?

[This recent article](http://www.webnots.com/fix-safari-slow-loading-pages-mac-os-x/) also has some good suggestions regarding slow page loading in Safari:

1. Change DNS settings of your Mac
2. Disable DNS prefetching
3. Change IPv6 settings
4. Cleanup Safari preferences file
5. Clear browsing history
6. Disable autofilling form data
7. Check installed plugins
8. Check browser extensions
9. Cleanup your memory
10. Chrome Vs Safari (remove non-Safari browsers)
11. Check Your Network Settings

Also check out [this recent article from LifeWire](https://www.lifewire.com/does-hosting-affect-page-load-speed-3473911) and please report back if you find a solution which works for you.

Comment: Safari Networking is only taking max 20% CPU when I open multiple sites this seems normal, but I will keep an eye on it

Comment: @john see the suggestions in the article

Comment: thanks, but I know how to use google ;). Non of the suggested fixes helped.

Comment: @john that contradicts your profile description ;)